# Can any one explain me why the below paragraph contains "has had" at the same time?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

> Prime Minister Narendra Modi’s decision to abruptly withdraw legal tender status for Rs.1,000 and Rs.500 notes to save the country from “the grip of corruption and black money” has had one predictable side effect.

In the above paragraph why 'had' is used followed by 'has'??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**have** functions both as a "lexical" verb and a "helper" aka "auxiliary" verb. When used as an auxiliary, **have** combines with the lexical verb to form a perfect tense, here, the present perfect.

The dog has<sup>helper</sup> eaten<sup>lexical</sup> its dinner.

He has<sup>helper</sup> had<sup>lexical</sup> surgery on his elbow.

"to have surgery", to undergo a surgical operation.

Answer (score 4):

The verb "have" is being used in two unrelated ways in this sentence.

1. As a lexical verb, *to have* an effect means to cause it: *Lowering the price of our product **had** the effect of boosting sales.*
2. As a helper verb, the present tense of *have* combines with a past participle to form the [present perfect tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html): *My brother **has** traveled to China.*

So **has had** [an effect] is the present perfect of **to have** [an effect]: an action happened in the past that caused the effect, and the action is now complete.

The present perfect can be used for a few different reasons, but [in context](http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/A-dampening-of-economic-activity/article16750137.ece), I think the author is saying that *the effect is still ongoing*. Modi's decision is in the past, but people are experiencing the effect in the present.

Compare to:

- Simple past: *Modi's decision **had** one predictable side effect.* This suggests the decision and the effect are both in the past.
- Past perfect: *Modi's decision **had had** one predictable side effect.* This might be used to tell a story about the people of today, from the perspective of the future. For example: *Although Modi knew his decision had had this one effect, he didn't yet know about the other effects it would have.*